# Stop resource greedy services from getting evicted in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, resources, kubernetes-pod

We have a data processing service that tries to utilize as much CPU and memory as possible. In VMs this service uses max CPU and memory available and keeps on running. But when we run this service to Kubernetes it gets evicted as soon as it hits resource limits. Is there a way to let the service hit max resource usage and not get evicted?

Comment: Have you tried to increase resource limits?

Comment: Kubelet requires some resources per node, which is probably why you're seeing eviction. There's no way around that. I'd recommend setting resource limits to whatever the math comes down to (total resource minus kubelet requirements).

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Increasing resource limits won't help since the service tries to utilize as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

> The kubelet is the primary "node agent" that runs on each node.  [[1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)]
>
> When you specify a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/), you can optionally specify how much of each resource a [container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/) needs. [[2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)]

@mmking has the point. Indeed kubelet requires some resources per node and that's the reason of seeing eviction.

And again like @mmking mentioned - unfortunately there's no way around that.

> I'd recommend setting resource limits to whatever the math comes down to (total resource minus kubelet requirements).

I agree with the sentence above. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) you can find documentation.

References:

[1] [*Kubelet*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)

[2] [*Manage resources containers*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)